# Is it possible to implement destructor for TypeScript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a some object instance on server side and his representation on client side. 
When I create an instance on client, his constructor say to server, that there is need to create associated object. And when this object(client side) is out from scope, I want say to server, that associated object should be deleted.
How I can do it without manual invoking `Destroy()` method each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, Javascript has a garbage collector. So, you have to make sure the object is eligible for garbage collection.

If you want to tell your object that you are done with it and it should specifically release any event listeners it has, then you can just create an ordinary method for doing that.

You can name the method `release()` or `deregister()` or anything you like. The idea is to tell the object to disconnect itself from anything else it is hooked up to (deregister event listeners, clear external object references, etc...). This method should be called manually at the appropriate time.

You can read more about the destructor paradigm [on this topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37462/why-is-the-object-destructor-paradigm-in-garbage-collected-languages-pervasively)

Answer (score 1):

It is possibly answered here [Is there destructor in typeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885625/is-there-destructor-in-typescript)
As JS uses garbage collector there is no way to predict when object will be destroyed. So no destructors

Comment: Sometimes class can contains intervals, and they should be stop before as they prevent garbage collector to clear memory, that's why I am looking for TS destructor.